# Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am working on an application that transform xml to another xml using xslt. A small sample data works fine, but when it goes live, it shows the Exception of type System.OutOfMemoryException. The product xml file has size over more than 600 mb. On Windows task manager, it shows the crash happens when the application memory usage is over 1.6 gb. I tried to increase the size of both physical memory and virtual memory. That doesn't help.

Any suggestions?

C#:

```
// Create the XsltSettings object with document() enabled and script disabled.
    XsltSettings xsltsettings = new XsltSettings(true, false);
    XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xslt.Load(this.XsltFile, xsltsettings, new XmlUrlResolver());

    // Create the writer.
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.IndentChars = "\t";
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
    settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto;
    settings.CloseOutput = false;

    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(OutFile.Replace(".xml", ".txt"));
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(InFile);
    reader.MoveToContent();
    // Execute the transformation.
    xslt.Transform(reader, null, writer);
    writer.Close();
    reader.Close();
```

xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns="http://www.ncr.com/rsd/WebOffice/ConfigurationManagement"
                xmlns:acm="http://www.ncr.com/rsd/WebOffice/ConfigurationManagement"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl acm">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/Data/Record">
      <xsl:variable  name="desc">
        <xsl:call-template name="StringReplace">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="desc" />
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select='"&apos;"' />
          <xsl:with-param name="by" select='"&apos;&apos;"' />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable  name="startdate">
        <xsl:call-template name="NumberofDays">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="sale_start_date"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>  
      <xsl:variable  name="quotes">'</xsl:variable>

      <xsl:value-of select="concat('(',
        key,
        ',',
        $quotes,
        normalize-space(substring($desc, 2, string-length($desc) - 2)),
        $quotes,
        ',',       
        sale_price div 100,
        ',',
        sale_deal,
        ',',
        $startdate,
        ',',
        sale_start_time,
        ')')"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position() = last()">;</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>,</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="StringReplace">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace"/>
    <xsl:param name="by"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$by"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="StringReplace">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="NumberofDays">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name= "year" select="floor($text div 10000)"/>
    <xsl:variable name= "month" select="floor(($text mod 10000) div 100)"/>
    <xsl:variable name= "day"  select="floor(($text mod 10000) mod 100)"/>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$month != 0 and $day !=0">
        <xsl:variable name= "yeardate">
          <xsl:call-template name="CalculateJulianDay">
            <xsl:with-param  name="year" select="$year"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="month" select="$month"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="day" select="$day"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name= "startdate">
          <xsl:call-template name="CalculateJulianDay">
            <xsl:with-param  name="year" select="$year"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="month" select="1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="day" select="1"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($year, format-number(number($yeardate)-number($startdate)+1,'000'))" ></xsl:value-of>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>0000000</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="CalculateJulianDay">
    <xsl:param name="year"/>
    <xsl:param name="month"/>
    <xsl:param name="day"/>

    <xsl:variable name="a" select="floor((14 - $month) div 12)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="$year + 4800 - $a"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="$month + 12 * $a - 3"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="$day + floor((153 * $m + 2) div 5) + $y * 365 +
      floor($y div 4) - floor($y div 100) + floor($y div 400) -
      32045"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<Data>
    <Record>
        <key>00000000000017</key>       
        <desc>"P&amp;G FIXTURE"</desc>       
        <sale_price>120</sale_price>
        <sale_deal>0</sale_deal>
        <sale_start_date>20121002</sale_start_date>
        <sale_start_time>0001</sale_start_time>
    </Record>
</Data>
```

Comment: You could watch memory used in Task Manager, performance tab and see how it is going

Comment: What exactly is your transform doing? That snippet of code alone tells us nothing. Show us your transform and perhaps a sample of the data, the problem is in there.

Comment: The following is not your problem if it crashes the first time, but your `TextWriter` and `XmlReader` should both be in `using` blocks: `using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(...)){using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(...)){...}}`.

Comment: Thanks. xslt and xml code snippet are added.

Comment: I tried to run the app using Oxygen XML editor, and got E Java heap space error. I guess it is xslt, but not c# issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing exactly what your xslt object is but guessing it is a XslCompiledTransform.  Have you seen this:  [MSDN Blog Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2011/09/26/effective-xml-part-5-something-went-really-wrong-outofmemoryexception-and-stackoverflowexception-thrown-when-using-xslcompiledtransform.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You might hit 2Gb limit for 32bit process size on 32bit system

If you move to 64bit system but continue to use 32bit process, your app size limit would be 4Gb

On 64bit system with 64bit process you're good up to 8Tb or so

Comment: The app was running on VM which is Windows server 2008 R2 standard, 64 bit with RAM 8GB. Not sure why 2GB limit still holds.

Comment: did you check with Task Manager? It will quickly tell you app size before crash

Comment: in task manager, it shows the crash happens with the memory size of 1.6 GB. The app is 32 bit. Why can the max memory go up to 4 GB?